# Is it possible to comment out an already defined environment?

Tags: environments, comments

I have defined the following environment for producing problem statements:

```
\newcounter{psctr}
\newcounter{probctr}[psctr]

\NewDocumentEnvironment{prob}{o}{%
\addtocounter{probctr}{1}
\vspace{.15in}

\IfNoValueTF{#1} {%
    \noindent\textbf{Problem \thepsctr.\theprobctr}%
}{%
    \noindent\textbf{Problem \thepsctr.\theprobctr} (#1 points) %
}%

\smallskip\noindent\ignorespaces%
}{}
```

I would like to show or hide `prob` instance throughout the document. I have tried `comment` package with `\excludecomment{comment}`, but this produces and error. Is there a way to comment out already defined environments?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `comment` package:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{xparse,comment}
\newcounter{psctr}
\newcounter{probctr}[psctr]

\NewDocumentEnvironment{prob}{o}
 {%
  \par
  \addvspace{.15in}%
  \addtocounter{probctr}{1}%
  \noindent\textbf{Problem \thepsctr.\theprobctr}%
  \IfNoValueF{#1}{ (#1 points)}%
  \par\nopagebreak\smallskip\noindent\ignorespaces%
 }
 {\par\addvspace{.15in}}

%\excludecomment{prob}

\begin{document}
test
\begin{prob}[2]
test
\end{prob}
\end{document}
```

Remove the `%` in front of `\excludecomment{prob}` to disable the environment.

I've made some fixes to your definition. It's better to use `\addvspace` instead of `\vspace` in such a situation, so the vertical space is not simply added; I added it also after the problem text, but two consecutive problems will have just one of the vertical spaces. Also `\nopagebreak` is necessary before `\smallskip` in order to avoid an unwanted page break between “Problem n” and the text.

Comment: Thanks for the improvements. May I ask what are the two `par` for?

Comment: @passerby51 `\par` is to ensure that `\addvspace` is between paragraphs.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `verbatim` package which defines a `comment` environment for this purpose.

So, writing

```
\let\prob\comment
\let\endprob\endcomment
```

you are saying that your `prob` environment should be treated as a comment.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[liststotoc,bibtotoc,headsepline]{scrreprt}%draft
\usepackage{xparse,verbatim}
\newcounter{psctr}
\newcounter{probctr}[psctr]

\NewDocumentEnvironment{prob}{o}{%
\addtocounter{probctr}{1}
\vspace{.15in}

\IfNoValueTF{#1} {%
    \noindent\textbf{Problem \thepsctr.\theprobctr}%
}{%
    \noindent\textbf{Problem \thepsctr.\theprobctr} (#1 points) %
}%

\smallskip\noindent\ignorespaces%
}{}
\let\prob\comment
\let\endprob\endcomment
\begin{document}
test
\begin{prob}
test
\end{prob}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Where in your code is the `verbatim` environment used?

Comment: @Mico `verbatim` *package* (which defines the `comment` environment) ....

Comment: @karlkoeller - it would be useful if this piece of information were made explicit. Not everyone knows that the `verbatim` package features an environment named `comment`.

Comment: @Mico indeed it would be useful...

Comment: @touhami I didn't, but you should add some explanations, perhaps.

Comment: @karlkoeller i asked you to do this

Comment: @touhami I hope the edit you asked for, is OK for you.

Comment: @touhami, thanks. I seems that the  `comment` package itself works.